# Auto Populate the the column field if the value is zero in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table `test` with this sample data:

```
id   name   user_id
-------------------
1     sd       0
3     ds       0
4     ss       0

... etc
```

Now I want to update the dummy value op the `user_id` column starts with 90000000001(12 digits) if the user id is zero.How do we achieve this?

I never came across this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to do this:

```
DECLARE @user_id bigint
SET @user_id = 90000000000
UPDATE test
SET @user_id= user_id = @user_id + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
Create Table Test (ID Int, Name Varchar(8000), User_Id BigInt)
Insert Test Values (1, 'Joe', 1)
Insert Test Values (2, 'John', 800)
Insert Test Values (3, 'Jerry', 0)
Insert Test Values (4, 'Jane', 100)
Insert Test Values (5, 'Jim', 0)
Insert Test Values (6, 'Jamie', 8997)

Update T Set T.User_ID = Q.Dummy
    From Test T
    Join (Select ID, Row_Number() Over (Order By ID) + 9000000000 Dummy From Test Where User_Id = 0) Q On Q.ID = T.ID

Select * From Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly then the following should do what you want:

```
    UPDATE  test
    SET     [user_id] = CAST(NewIDs.new_user_id AS BIGINT)
    FROM    test
    INNER JOIN  (
                    SELECT  [id]
                            ,[name]
                            ,'9' + RIGHT('0000000000'+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [id]) AS VARCHAR(11)),11)  AS [new_user_id]
                    FROM    test ZeroID  
                    WHERE   [user_id] = 0
                ) NewIDs ON NewIDs.id = test.id
```